# Common deep learning practices in NLP for text classification

Tags: deep-learning, text-mining, nlp

Are there any articles about best modern techniques in text classification (not only for English texts, but in general)? In particular, I'm interested:

- what kind of text preprocessing techniques are usually useful? Can you share with some good open-source text preprocessors?
- what kind of neural networks architectures one should try first on a new text classification problem? What kind of architectures should be solid baselines?
- what are the "rules of thumb" for choosing the size of the dictionary? maximum number of words to be left (in sequence padding)? word embeddings dimension?

Would be great if you could share articles, or (even better!) the must-read research papers, or anything else you find useful about this topic. If you could share with your own experience in the comments, that would be greatly appreciated, too!